# Как скопировать текст по нажатию?

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на button "копировать" копировалось в буфер обмена вот такое вот значение: 7777777.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("btn");
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.textContent)
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">копировать</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь скопировать в буфер обмена текстовое значение элемента button, а это строка "копировать", а не "7777777". И еще вы забыли добавить обработчик события click на саму кнопку. Код будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("7777777");
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Копировать</button>
```

Comment: лучше приводить воспроизводимый пример